# JS error as: var is not defined. How can i send value on function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, node.js, express

Now I have this code to create sitemap.xml when I run /sitemap.xml

```
 database = firebase.database();
    var ref = database.ref('urls');
    ref.on('value', gotData, errData);

    function errData(err){
        console.log('Error!');
        console.log(err);
    }  


function gotData(data){
    result = data.val() 
    return Object.keys(result)
   .filter(key => result[key].last_res > 5)
   .map(key => ({url: '/' + result[key].url_site + '/'}));
    var urls = gotData(data); 
}
```

when i try running console.log(urls) in gotData(data) function, it returns as

```
{ salmon: 
   { count: 1,
     last_res: 10,
     url_site: 'salmon' },
  'salmon-food': 
   { count: 1,
     last_res: 601,
     url_site: 'salmon-food' } }
```

I need to return 'urls' in gotData(data) to create sitemap.xml.

```
var sitemap = sm.createSitemap({ 
            hostname: 'xxx.com',
            cacheTime: 600000,
            urls: urls

        });
app.get('/sitemap.xml', function(req, res) {
    sitemap.toXML( function (err, xml) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).end();
        }
        res.header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
        res.send( xml );
    });
    });
}
```

But now its error on var = sitemap as

```
urls: urls -> urls is not defined
```

So how can I fix it?

Comment: Where is *urls* declared?

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning and returning in one line. You either need to define the variable and then return it, or just return the result directly without assigning to a variable.

```
return Object.keys(result)
  .filter(key => result[key].last_res > 5)
  .map(key => ({url: '/' + result[key].url_site + '/'}));
```

It's also not clear where you are defining the `urls` variable that you are passing in the `sm.createSitemap()` function. Make sure that it exists within the scope that you are defining `var sitemap`.

You are likely missing a line similar to the following:

```
var urls = gotData(data);
```

Comment: If i return as above how can i get value on this line `urls: urls` ?

Comment: I doubt that this is relevant. When the return statement is executed, in non-strict mode *urls* will be created and assigned a value. That same value is returned by the function. In strict mode, it will throw a reference error (unless *urls* is declared somewhere not shown).

Comment: @MoomooSoso see my additions.

Comment: @doublesharp I've update code as above but it still error as `ReferenceError: urls is not defined`

Comment: @MoomooSoso You'll need to be more specific about where the error is being generated. You can use the Chrome debugging tools to see the line.